# Sorting for Ajax Combo-Box

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am wondering if there is any other way of sorting ajax combo box apart from this following example;

```
Public Class ListItemComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of ListItem)

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As ListItem, ByVal y As ListItem) As Integer _
        Implements IComparer(Of ListItem).Compare

        Dim c As New CaseInsensitiveComparer
        Return c.Compare(x.Text, y.Text)
    End Function
End Class

Public Shared Sub SortDropDown(ByVal cbo As AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox)
    Dim lstListItems As New List(Of ListItem)
    For Each li As ListItem In cbo.Items
        lstListItems.Add(li)
    Next
    lstListItems.Sort(New ListItemComparer)
    cbo.Items.Clear()
    cbo.Items.AddRange(lstListItems.ToArray)
End Sub

----------Binding and Sorting Combo-Box----------
    ddlClients.DataTextField = "ClientName"
    ddlClients.DataValueField = "ClientID"
    ddlClients.DataBind()

    SortDropDown(ddlClients)
```

---

In the SP, i am using order by clause on Client Name but somehow combox doesn't bind ClientNames in order.

I like to to place this function in CommonFunction Class so i can call it from different places within the project. I am not able to add the above function in the BusinessLayer becuase of 'AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox'

Comment: Why can you not have `AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox` in your `CommonFunction` class?

Comment: Seems like it'd be much easier to sort in the data source.

Comment: Thanks. Sort method done the trick.Dim clients As List(Of Client)  clients.Sort()